# Swift equivalent for UIImage with CGImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiimage

**What is the Swift equivalent for the following expression?**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *assets;

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[self.assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] thumbnail]];
```

I tried:

```
private var assets: [AnyObject]

cell.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: self.assets[indexPath.row].thumbnail())
```

But this gives the error:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'inBundle' in call
```

Edit: `self.assets` has objects from the following expression:

```
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

        if (result) {
            [self.assets insertObject:result atIndex:0];
        }

    };
```

Comment: What are the objects in `self.assets`?

Comment: @matt See my edit. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the property like this:

```
var assets: [ALAsset]
```

And then, in the actual code of some method:

```
let thumb = self.assets[indexPath.row].thumbnail().takeUnretainedValue()
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage:thumb)
```

In the property declaration, I'm revealing to the compiler what this is really an array of. Otherwise, it has no idea that `thumbnail()` is a real method or what sort of thing it returns.

In the first line of the actual code, I'm dealing with the fact that AssetLibrary framework doesn't have memory management info; you can't proceed in Swift unless you resolve this somehow.

So, by the next line we've got an actual CGImage and can just proceed to use it.

Comment: When do I have to use ``takeUnretainedValue()``or ``takeRetainedValue()``?

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048826/takeunretainedvalue-vs-takeretainedvalue