# How to read Finder icons (left source list) on OS X using Swift - deprecated method

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, deprecated, core-foundation

I will start new thread since this question is deprecated [How to read Finder icons (left source list) on OS X using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756401/how-to-read-finder-icons-left-source-list-on-os-x-using-swift)
as Apple source code says:

```
@available(OSX, introduced=10.5, deprecated=10.11, message="This functionality is no longer supported on OS X.")
public func LSSharedFileListCreate(inAllocator: CFAllocator!, _ inListType: CFString!, _ listOptions: AnyObject!) -> Unmanaged<LSSharedFileList>!
```

What is the proper way to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761105/3475858) in OS X 10.11 El Capitan?