# How do I return an Unmanaged<CGColor>! in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgcolor, lottie

I'm using Lottie (animation framework) and one of the delegates I'm trying to use is expecting me to return an `Unmanaged<CGColor>!`

This is the definition:

```
color(forFrame currentFrame: CGFloat, startKeyframe: CGFloat, endKeyframe: CGFloat, interpolatedProgress: CGFloat, start startColor: CGColor!, end endColor: CGColor!, currentColor interpolatedColor: CGColor!) -> Unmanaged<CGColor>!
```

If I just try to return `UIColor.white.cgColor` I get an error that says

`Cannot convert return expression of type 'CGColor' to return type 'Unmanaged<CGColor>!'`

I already tried going through their documentation but their example only shows to use it like this:

```
let colorBlock = LOTColorBlockCallback { (currentFrame, startKeyFrame, endKeyFrame, interpolatedProgress, startColor, endColor, interpolatedColor) -> Unmanaged<CGColor> in
    return aColor
}
```

So how can I return the proper type?

Thanks

Comment: https://nshipster.com/unmanaged/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create `Unmanaged` instance by calling `passRetained` or `passUnretained` static function like this:

`Unmanaged.passRetained(UIColor.white.cgColor)`

But keep in mind, that for future usage of this variable should be handled with `takeRetainedValue` if you decided to use `passRetained()` or with `takeUnretainedValue()` function if you will use `passUnretained`. If that would not be done - you would have memory leak or possible crash.

Comment: As the API is written in Obj-C, the block is most likely expecting a +0 return value (as that is the default convention for methods not in the `alloc`/`init`/`copy` family), so  `Unmanaged.passRetained(UIColor.white.cgColor).autorelease()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could get it by using [`takeRetainedValue()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged/1539754-takeretainedvalue) method in `Unmanaged`  structure:

> Gets the value of this unmanaged reference as a managed reference and
>   consumes an unbalanced retain of it.

In your case, the instance type should be `CGColor`, therefore:

```
let cgColor = unmanagedColor.takeRetainedValue()
```

should solves it. Note that `unmanagedColor` is the output of calling the definition you mentioned:

```
color(forFrame currentFrame: CGFloat, startKeyframe: CGFloat, endKeyframe: CGFloat, interpolatedProgress: CGFloat, start startColor: CGColor!, end endColor: CGColor!, currentColor interpolatedColor: CGColor!) -> Unmanaged<CGColor>!
```

Furthermore, you might want to check:

[When to use takeUnretainedValue() or takeRetainedValue() to retrieve Unmanaged Objects in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048826/when-to-use-takeunretainedvalue-or-takeretainedvalue-to-retrieve-unmanaged-o)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, although I was asking how to create the output as unmanaged, not consume the output. Valuable info though, so thanks!